# Fetch image from mysql database using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have stored my images in mysql database.When I am trying to retrieve them I am getting my image along with a lengthy string of buffer.Here goes my code:

```
var sql ="SELECT rname,image FROM recipes WHERE ringre LIKE '%" +items[0]+"%' ";
    for( var i=1;i<items.length;i++){
        sql = sql + "AND ringre LIKE '%"+items[+i]+"%' ";
    }

    console.log(sql);

    con.query(sql, function(err,result){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            console.log(result);
            var result1 = JSON.stringify(result);
            res.render("recipes_response",{ data: result[0].image.toString('base64'), recipes: result1});
        }
    });

 });
```

and the result is:
[image]

But I just want the image and rname.
Will anybody help me out?

Comment: you have `rname` and `image` in the result. please clarify your issue

Comment: I have but I don't want the image's description.I just want image and the rname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using EJS templates, so if you write:

```
con.query(sql, function(err,result){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }else{
        res.render("recipes_response", { data: result[0].image.toString('base64'), rname: result[0].rname});
    }
});
```

Then in your /views/ folder create recipes_response.ejs

**recipes_response.ejs**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Image test</h3>
        <div>
            <h4>Recipe name: <%= rname %></h4>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64, <%= data %>" alt="DB Image" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Multiple Recipes**

```
con.query(sql, function(err,result){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }else{
        let recipes = result.map(row => { return { rname: row.rname, image: row.image.toString('base64')}});
        res.render("recipes_response_list", { recipes } );
    }
});
```

Then create a new template:

**recipes_response_list.ejs**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Recipes</h3>
        <%  for (let recipe of recipes){ %> %>
        <div>
            <h4>Recipe name: <%= recipe.rname %></h4>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64, <%= recipe.image %>" alt="Recipe image" />
        </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, glad to be of help.. happy coding! :-)

Comment: Another query...How to retrieve and display multiple images and rnames of same ringre

Comment: For example I have an ingredient(ringre) of name herbs.With this ingredient I have multiple recipes with images in my database,so now I wanted to retrieve all rnames and images with herbs ingredient.How can I do that

Comment: You can loop over values in EJS, so if you create an array of items, say arrayData, e.g. render('viewname', { recipeArray: [...] } ), then in the template: <%  for (let recipe of reciperArray){ %>.. I'll update in the answer!

Comment: I've updated the answer, NB, I've added a new template as well.

Comment: Great, very happy to hear it!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214165/discussion-between-user14-and-terry-lennox).